# Form field onblur event issue (really strange!)

Tags: javascript, events, onblur

I am currently struggling with a really really strange issue.

- I have a telephone number form field
- There's a function that fires onblur and validates whether the value is valid or not
- Every **second time** I do a blur, it validates as false, even if the value is correct and the value hasn't changed!

I have set up a small test case: http://jsfiddle.net/U3jwx/2/

Just click into the field and afterwards outside it - multiple times!

How can that be? The value does not even change! 
I suppose it has something to do with the validation function...

Comment: I tried multiple times, it always shows true. Using Chrome here.

Comment: Dunno if you changed it but it works fine for me in Chrome and FF - And IE!

Comment: Hmm seems to be a Firefox only issue!

Comment: Problem is present with FF 3.6.13 Ununtu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reset your regular expression's lastIndex to 0 between calls.

```
var validatePhoneNumber = function(val) {        
        var re = /^\+([0-9]{1,3})([\-\s]{0,1})([0-9]{2,6})([\-\s]{0,1})([0-9\-\s]{0,})$/gi;
        re.lastIndex = 0;
        return re.test(val);
};
```

Comment: The regex has just been constructed, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Great! Works now as expexted. Didn't know that property till now. I also thought that this could not be a problem as the regex is rebuilt every time. but this is not the case as it seems :-)

Comment: Maybe some FF versions are caching the RegExp somehow? is it a bug?

Comment: @Alex: or, better (IMHO), remove the `g` flag.